# Implementing a named search criteria

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm looking for implementation ideas for the following scenario:

I have a search screen with a bunch of dropdowns and free form text fields/text areas. I would like to provide the option of saving the search criteria for the logged in user so they can reuse that criteria later if they want to.  Some options I could think of are name/value pairs, XML & serialized objects.  Are there other options and what are your recommendations on the best option.  We use glassfish, hibernate, oracle, j2ee 1.4 & java 6.. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: How about using something like [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/), which is a embedded database.

Answer (score 0):

I think as part of your validation logic you can persist the  name value pairs that were used for search. For enterprise there are no personalization features that can be easily adopted, depending upon the requirements we have to go with one of the above.